# Load big amount of data - Allowed memory size exhausted

Tags: performance, caching, architecture, scaling, software-design

I have JAVA Spring Boot application (I'll call it A1) that is connected to Rabbit. The A1 receives data and saves it to the database(MySql) (I'll call database DB1).You can imagine this data as football matches with appropriate markets and outcomes.We are receiving data for the next 10 days over A1 app, and that data is stored in the database.

One more thing is worth to emphasize that every football match has 4 markets and every market has 7 outcomes.

I will explain how DB1 looks like.There are 3 tables (matches, markets, outcomes) worth mentioning besides other tables.Those are related in the way:matches 1.....* marketsmarkets 1.....* outcomes
Data that is received over A1 is constantly updating(every second some update is received for the football events from the current moment plus 2 hours).
There is another PHP Symfony application (I'll call it S1). This application serves as a REST API.

There is one more frontend application (I'll call it F1) that is communicating with S1 over HTTP in order to retrieve data from the database.
F1 application is sending an HTTP request to S1 in order to retrieve this data (matches with markets and outcomes) but the date time frame is from the current moment plus 7 days (business requirement).

When an HTTP request is sent to S1 error occurred because there are over 10 000 football matches plus bets and outcomes.

> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in.

I am considering two options in order to solve this issue and please if neither of my options are good enough, I would appreciate if You could suggest me some solution to my problem.

1. Option - F1 iterate per day and sending 7 HTTP requests asynchronously to S1 in order to retrieve data for all 7 days.
2. Option - F1 sends an HTTP request to S1. S1 returns data only for today, and the next 6 days is sending over a socket iterating per day, using https://pusher.com/ or something similar.

One more thing to emphasize is the number of this HTTP that we count is two per second and it tends to grow.

Answer (score 0):

10K matches is turning into 134 MB of data?  You are using more than 13K for each record...  Likely you are trying to make your data structure too flat, duplicating metadata on matches/bets/etc into a single flat record.  Try making your objects hierarchical, having a match have bets instead of single-row objects.

If not, then you have an inefficiency in your processing of the data that we cannot diagnose remotely.

You would do even better if you did more processing server-side instead of sending the raw data over the wire.  The more you can answer questions *inside* of S1 instead of sending the data to the client, the less data you will have to send.